# partprobe error right after reboot

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

No partition operations have been performed between power-on and this error message. Any idea why partprobe would say this?

Note it's an identical error message for both /dev/sda  and /dev/sdb although those disks have nothing in common (one mounted at / and SATA, the other mounted at /build and USB, no common filesystem or such).

Both have two partitions only according to fdisk and parted.

This is aarch64 (Arch Linux).

````
> sudo partprobe
Error: Partition(s) 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
Error: Partition(s) 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.```

Add-on: I removed all traces of /dev/sdb from /etc/fstab, rebooted, and get the above error message just for /dev/sda. Then I plug in the external USB drive, and without mounting or doing anything else, the partprobe output goes back to having the line for /dev/sdb as well.

Also, running strace on partprobe shows it is attempting to access all devices from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda255, same for sdb. This sounds weird.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using gparted on Fedora. Based upon some googling *(is "G" capitalized when using it as a verb?)* it appears to be a regression error introduced in or around Kernel 5.8.8.

I just installed Kernel 5.8.11 and it is fixed.

I didn't try the interim releases.